# Cambio de conexión a SQL, de forma dinámica en .Net Core 2.x

Tags: sql-server, .net, asp.net-core

estoy haciendo un desarrollo en .Net Core el cual despues del login de usuario debe mostrar una lista de empresas (las cuales esta relacionada a una base de datos cada una), al seleccionar una empresa esta debe cambiar la conexión a una bd de acuerdo al registro seleccionado.

Mi duda es como puedo hacer que se cambie la conexión de "DefaultConnection" a otra base de datos?

He logrado que se cambie la conexión pasandole como parámetro otra cadena que configure en el appsetings.json pero todo esto de forma manual, no se como puedo invocar desde mi controlador a ConfigureServices.

en el appsettings.json lo tengo de la siguiente forma:

```
 {
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=EQUIPO-COGNITIV;Database=SEQTOR_Analitycs_N1;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
    "CrisfeConnection":  "Server=EQUIPO-COGNITIV;Database=SEQTOR_Crisfe;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

En el ConfigureService puedo usar una cadena dependiendo de una u otra conexión

```
 string connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(connection));
```

Y si quisiera usar una conexión alternativa fija lo haría de esta forma, tambien en ConfigureService:

```
services.AddDbContext<CrisfeDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("CrisfeConnection")));
```

Pero lo que necesito es que sea mas dinámica y establecerla desde un método de mi controlador ya que podre crear tantas bases de datos se necesiten a futuro y la idea es administrar esto por base de datos.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Estas realizando una app multi-tenant, segun tu comentario. Es decir dependiendo de "algo" se configura para utilizar una u otra DB. Pero deberias ver cual es la mejor opcion de guardar este "valor previo seleccionado". Puede ser por la url? empresa1.dominio.com y empresa2.dominio.com? Porque asi podemos armar un [middleware personalizado](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-2.2) que obtenga este valor del la url (en vez del dominio, subdominio, puede ser algun otro valor alli). puede ser asi? Y asi vemos de recomendarte lo mejor

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias Jose Fernandez, evaluaré la posibilidad de usar un middleware personalizado.

Por otra parte la solución que he encontrado para cubrir mi necesidad ha sido muy sencilla, creo que me estaba complicando mucho, la idea es tener un entorno multi empresas, que cada base de datos represente una empresa como tal a la que los usuarios que se logean en una BD principal que contiene los usuarios y los roles luego puedan entrar a una empresa u otra según sus permisos, lo que hice fue lo siguiente:

1.- Cree una variable global que almacena la cadena de conexión en string y concatenada para dar flexibilidad.

```
public class Public_Class
    {
        public string BD_Conn {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public EmpresaDbContext Conex_BD { get; set; }

        public Public_Class()
        {
            Establece_conexion();
        }

        public void Establece_conexion()
        {
            if (BD_Conn != null)
            {
                var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<EmpresaDbContext>();
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(BD_Conn);
                Conex_BD = new EmpresaDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
            }            
        }

    }
```

2.- En el startup hago la declaración para poder usarla, en ConfigureServices

3.- Llamo mi conexión desde cada controlador

```
private readonly IOptions<Public_Class> _DbConn;

public HomeController(ApplicationDbContext context, EmpresaDbContext Econtext, IOptions<Public_Class> public_Class)
        {
            _context = context;
            _DbConn = public_Class;
            _DbConn.Value.Conex_BD = Econtext;
        }
```

De esta manera puedo acceder a muchas bases de datos sin tener que estar creando un contexto para cada empresa que se cree, puedo gestionarlo por BD fácilmente y preparo mi entorno para lo que a futuro quiero hacer que es que cada usuario cree su empresa mediante scripts de SQL.

Muchas gracias.-

Comment: Carlos Zapata como hiciste la declaracion en el startup para poder usarla, en ConfigureServices?